# Boot up graphics issue on 22.04.3 update

Tags: boot, drivers, 22.04

A recent update to 22.04.3 llvpipe (LLVM 15.07, 1280 bits) seems to hang at startup on a graphics driver mode such that I only see a blank screen where I would normally get a login panel or a Ubuntu logo. If I perform a GNU GRUB  interrupt, Advanced Options..., 5.15.0-86-generic (recovery mode) the system will run in 1024x768 graphics mode, far below the capabilities of the hardware. The laptop is a Dell Latitude E6510, i7 CPU M 620 @ 2.67GHz x 4.

I'd like to run at the higher graphic mode in non-recovery mode as previously without having to reinstall the OS or other radical step to correct. Is there any rollback-update feature that I can try as well, or other diagnostic that is applicable? Any advise is appreciated.